# WPF Databinding TextBox to integer property in another object

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, numeric

I have what I think is a very simple databinding question (I'm still new to WPF).
I have a class (simplified for this question)

```
public class ConfigurationData
{
    public int BaudRate { get; set; } 
}
```

In MainWindow.Xaml.cs I have a private member variable:

```
private ConfigurationData m_data;
```

and a method

```
void DoStuff()
{
   // do a bunch of stuff (read serial port?) which may result in calling...
   m_data.BaudRate = 300; // or some other value depending on logic
}
```

In my MainWindow gui, I'd like to have a TextBox that displays m_data.BaudRate AND allows for two way binding. The user should be able to enter a value in the textbox, and the textbox should display new values that we're caused by "DoStuff()" method. I've seen tons of examples on binding to another property of a control on MainWindow, and binding to a datacollection, but no examples of binding to a property of another object.  I would think that my example is about as simple as it get, with the nagging annoyance that I'm binding to an integer, not a string, and if possible, I would like the user to only be able to enter integers.
BTW I considered using a numeric up/down, but decided against it as there did not seem to be a lot of support/examples of non-commercial numeric up/down controls.  Plus, it could be an awfully big range of numbers to spin through.

I think a pointer to one good example would get me on my way.
Many thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: I should have said that I think a pointer to one good example would set me on my way.

Comment: This does not work (syntac error) <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={m_data}, Path=BaudRate}" Height="23" Margin="137,70,21,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />  I did see that one can setup a "resource" in the Xaml.  This would seem to be overkill for me.  Can't I just do it inline somehow? It's only one time I'm going to bind to m_data.    Aside: Is it possible to format code or use the return key in comments :) ?

Comment: Just wanted to note that a numeric up-down (or spinner) control also helps with preventing non-numerical keyboard input and min/max validations, not just the actual spinning of numbers. I think there's one in Bag of Tricks that does the job decently (you only need to style it properly).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alex.  Unfortunately, I saw your comment at work where we use Visual Studio 2008 (sigh).  The "Bag of Tricks" (http://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot is what I saw) seems to only have the Visual Studio 2010 code.  I'll look at it at home.

Answer (score 19):

Although this question is old, it's a good one, and is rarely answered succinctly. Let me offer a simplified solution for others who come upon this page.

In order to support two-way binding, your initial `ConfigurationData` class must be expanded to support property changes. Otherwise the changes in `DoStuff()` will not be reflected in the UI textbox. Here is a typical way of doing that:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public class ConfigurationData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _BaudRate;
    public int BaudRate
    {
        get { return _BaudRate; }
        set { _BaudRate = value; OnPropertyChanged("BaudRate"); }
    }

    //below is the boilerplate code supporting PropertyChanged events:
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

I choose to put the textbox binding right in the XAML (I've also added a button to DoStuff), like so:

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBox Width="96" Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding BaudRate}" />
    <Button  Width="96" Canvas.Top="25" Content="ChangeNumber" Click="DoStuff"/>
</Canvas>
```

The tricky part is gluing this all together. For that you'll need to define your DataContext. I prefer to do this in the constructor of my main window. Here's the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ConfigurationData m_data;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_data = new ConfigurationData();
        this.DataContext = m_data;  // This is the glue that connects the
                                    // textbox to the object instance
    }

    private void DoStuff(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_data.BaudRate += 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Is there an easier way without defining such a public class and it's own methods?
Why I am asking is because when I was using the textbox together with a slidebar, actually I can bind the name of slide bar as an element name together with my textbox.

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slValue, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" />
        <Slider Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="slValue" />

So there must be something existing, used in slidebar,

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way (please tell me!), but here's one way I cobbled together that works.  It seems that there should be an easier way.
For the property BaudRate use:

```
public int BaudRate
    {
        get
        { 
            return m_baudRate;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (value != m_baudRate)
            {
                m_baudRate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BaudRate");//OnPropertyChanged definition left out here, but it's pretty standard
            }
        }
    }
```

For the XAML, I have no significant markup:

```
<TextBox  Height="23" Margin="137,70,21,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
```

Now this is the messy part... Create class for validation:

```
public class IntRangeRule : ValidationRule
{
    // See ValidationRule Class
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value is int) // replace with your own logic or more robust handling...
            {
                return new ValidationResult(true, "Fine");
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or ");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
        }


    }
}
```

And then in the constructor of Window1 (MainWindow), have:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("BaudRate");
        myBinding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        ValidationRule rule = new IntRangeRule();
                    myBinding.ValidationRules.Add(rule);
        myBinding.Source = m_data; // where m_data is the member variable of type ConfigurationData
        textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

All my attempts to do everything in markup failed.  Better ways?

Dave